# how to color advanceddatagrid column background based on condition?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, advanceddatagrid, itemrenderers

AdvancedDataGrid does not allow  me to  use  column level itemrenderizer nor style function using which i  should  fill the background color of  the  column on specific conditions on each row .

I tried  the  style function  where it  changes  the  text color but not the background color for the cell >i do not  have the idea  about how  to  use  a  itemrender to  override  properties  of  ADG .

Please  help  me i tried  all possible ways and this is  my last  hope to get  some  solution 
 My  code:

```
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup headerText="Time Frame">    
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="region" headerText="Region"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="cat1" headerText="Cat 1"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="cat2" headerText="Cat 2"/>
        </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup> 
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn id="levelfield" dataField="level" headerText="level"  styleFunction="myColStyleFunc" />
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup headerText="Role">    
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="operation" headerText="Operation" />
        </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup>
```

Function

```
public function myColStyleFunc(data:Object, col:AdvancedDataGridColumn):Object
{
    if(data["level"]== 'Level 1'){
        return {backgroundColor:0x00FF00};
}
```

Comment: Do you want to color all the cells of a particular column?

Comment: Also post some code that can compile.

Comment: yes in particular  i  want to  dispaly  the RAG status  based  on  value and null values  the original  color

Comment: Are you using Flex 3 SDK or Flex 4 as we can use ADG in both ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to write your own item renderer overriding `set data` method for that as shown below.  Name of the class is ColoredHeaderRenderer.

```
<s:MXAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                                  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                                  xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                                  focusEnabled="true" xmlns:local="*">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            override public function set data(value:Object):void {
                  if(value.Actual == 29134) {
                      lblData.getTxt().background = true;
                      lblData.getTxt().backgroundColor = '0xFFFF00';
                  } else if(value.Actual == 38865) {
                      lblData.getTxt().background = true;
                      lblData.getTxt().backgroundColor = '0xFF0000';
                  }
                   super.data=value;  
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <local:CustomLabel id="lblData" top="0" left="0" right="0" bottom="0" text="{listData.label}"/>
</s:MXAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer>
```

I have tried this with the following sample code:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" xmlns:local="*">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            [Bindable]
            private var dpHierarchy:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
                {Region:"Southwest", categories: [
                    {Region:"Arizona", categories: [ 
                        {Territory_Rep:"Barbara Jennings", Actual:38865, Estimate:40000}, 
                        {Territory_Rep:"Dana Binn", Actual:29885, Estimate:30000}]},  
                    {Region:"Central California", categories: [ 
                        {Territory_Rep:"Joe Smith", Actual:29134, Estimate:30000}]},  
                    {Region:"Nevada", categories: [ 
                        {Territory_Rep:"Bethany Pittman", Actual:52888, Estimate:45000}]},  
                    {Region:"Northern California", categories: [ 
                        {Territory_Rep:"Lauren Ipsum", Actual:38805, Estimate:40000}, 
                        {Territory_Rep:"T.R. Smith", Actual:55498, Estimate:40000}]},  
                    {Region:"Southern California", categories: [ 
                        {Territory_Rep:"Alice Treu", Actual:44985, Estimate:45000}, 
                        {Territory_Rep:"Jane Grove", Actual:44913, Estimate:45000}]}
                ]}
            ]);
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:AdvancedDataGrid width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:dataProvider>
            <mx:HierarchicalData source="{dpHierarchy}" 
                                 childrenField="categories"/>
        </mx:dataProvider>
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Region"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Territory_Rep"
                                       headerText="Territory Rep"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Actual" itemRenderer="ColoredHeaderRenderer"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Estimate"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
</s:Application>
```

And it works fine as shown below:
[image]

Comment: my  doubt wouid be silly  but  i wanted  to  know  as  u  used  a itemrenderer  coloredheader... where did u  create this  did u use  a action script file or created  a  mxml  separately ..

Comment: You can create an mxml file and the code for that is the first snippet I have posted.

Comment: my  doubt wouid be silly  but  i wanted  to  know  as  u  used  a itemrenderer  coloredheader... where did u  create this  did u use  a action script file or created  a  mxml  separately ..  local:customelabel  tag is created by  ur self  wht is this  referring to  because when i  try  to excetue ur  code  with  in  my  packge  it  throws  error in  lblData.getTxt() Access of possibly undefined property background through a reference with static type spark.components:Label.